# How do I stop Android speaking my commands?

Tags: voice-command

Suddenly (OK so I may accidentally have triggered a setting somewhere) my android phone (LG v20 Standard Android) has started speaking all the touch commands I do.

For example, if I start from a blanked locked screen and turn it on the device says
"Screen on. the time" Then after a pause, "Screen Off" as it turns off the screen

If I type in characters it speaks every letter/character as I press the key (makes passwords tricky!!)

If I try to close an app with the X  I
press the x it says "Dismiss button. Double tap to activate"
I double tap and it says " app dismissed"

But worst of all swipe no longer works. So I cant swipe up to see what is on the bottom of a page; I cant swipe left to see other pages of apps etc etc

Please, how do I get back to a normal silent android!
TFAI

Comment: Sounds like talkback is on. you could probably OK google or use navbar to get into settings, from there just do [this](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007123?hl=en-GB) to turn talkback off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Tap Home key > Tools > Settings > General tab > Accessibility > Vision. Then, disable Talkback

**Method 2**

Hold <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> for more than 3 seconds to disable (or enable) Talkback as described in [this answer from XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78648919&postcount=2).

Comment: Lovely Thanks. Though I could not make Vol up and Vol down work. Staggered why anyone would want that feature!!

Comment: Did any of the methods solve the problem?

Comment: If yes, you can mark the response as answered.

Comment: Very happy to but HOW to I mark the question as answered?

Comment: You should take a tour of how the site work [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).